# How Can I Avoid view State In my asp page

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp.net and i am new developer. I want to avoid using `viewstate` in my page. I have two content Place holder like this:

```
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
  </asp:Content >
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyContent" runat="server">
  </asp:Content >
```

Can I do something with the `Contentplaceholder` OR  how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Have nothing to do with ContentPlaceholder You Just need to Define Enable ViewState to False like this:

```
  <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Masters/CliqueCityHomeMaster.master"
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CliqueCityHome.aspx.cs" EnableViewState="false" Inherits="CliqueCityWeb._Default" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from your web config by setting the the

```
<system.web>
<pages enableViewState="false" />
//other stuff
</system.web>
```

This will turn off view state for whole site.

For a particular page use EnableViewState="false" in wireups at the top of page

Have this link for more info on this.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A technique for doing this is to use a different [PageStatePersister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pagestatepersister.aspx). PageStatePersister is a base class in the .Net framework that saves ViewState. By default, pages use the [HiddenFieldPageStatePersister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.hiddenfieldpagestatepersister.aspx), which saves all your viewstate in a hidden field on the page; alternatively you can use the [SessionPageStatePersister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.sessionpagestatepersister.aspx), which instead saves your viewstate in session state on the server - which means it isn't transmitted on every round trip to your client.

To use the SessionPageStatePersister, in your page code you need to add:

```
protected override PageStatePersister PageStatePersister
{
    get
    {
        return new SessionPageStatePersister(this);
    }
}
```